# Show array of meta_value in Edit Post Coloum

Tags: custom-field, metabox, array, sql, meta-value

what I'm trying to do is add a new coloumn to Edit post page (done) and in that coloumn show data taken from a set of custom fields (partially done).

This is my code (I use it as a plugin so it simpler to modify it).
It adds the metabox in posts so I can easily add custom fields.

```
<?php
// the plugin base directory
global $maismeta_base_dir;
$maismeta_base_dir = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);

// Add the Meta Box
function add_custom_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'custom_meta_box', // $id
        'Impostazioni di ricerca', // $title 
        'show_custom_meta_box', // $callback
        'post', // $page
        'normal', // $context
        'high'); // $priority
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box');

// Field Array
$prefix = 'custom_';
$custom_meta_fields = array(
    array (
        'label' => __('Proprietario','maismeta'),
        'desc'  => __('Inserisci le informazioni sul proprietario.','maismeta'),
        'id'    => $prefix.'textarea_proprietario',
        'type'  => 'textarea',
    ),
    array (
        'label' => __('Sesso affittuario','maismeta'),
        'desc'  => __('Inserisci il sesso disponibile.','maismeta'),
        'id'    => $prefix.'checkbox_group_sesso',
        'type'  => 'checkbox_group',
        'options' => array (
            'Uomo' => array (
                'label' => __('Uomo','maismeta'),
                'value' => 'Uomo'
            ),
            'Donna' => array (
                'label' => __('Donna','maismeta'),
                'value' => 'Donna'
            ),
            'Altro' => array (
                'label' => __('Altro','maismeta'),
                'value' => 'Altro'
            )
        )
    ),
    array (
        'label' => __('Numero occupanti','maismeta'),
        'desc'  => __('Inserisci il numero degli occupanti.','maismeta'),
        'id'    => $prefix.'checkbox_group_occupanti',
        'type'  => 'checkbox_group',
        'options' => array (
            '1' => array (
                'label' => __('1','maismeta'),
                'value' => '1'
            ),
            '2' => array (
                'label' => __('2','maismeta'),
                'value' => '2'
            ),
            '3' => array (
                'label' => __('3','maismeta'),
                'value' => '3'
            ),
            '4' => array (
                'label' => __('4','maismeta'),
                'value' => '4'
            ),
            '5' => array (
                'label' => __('5','maismeta'),
                'value' => '5'
            ),
            '6' => array (
                'label' => __('6','maismeta'),
                'value' => '6'
            ),
            '7' => array (
                'label' => __('7','maismeta'),
                'value' => '7'
            ),
            '8' => array (
                'label' => __('8','maismeta'),
                'value' => '8'
            ),
        )
    ),
    array (
        'label' => __('Facolt&agrave; di riferimento','maismeta'),
        'desc'  => __('Scegli le facolt&agrave; di riferimento.','maismeta'),
        'id'    => $prefix.'checkbox_group_facolta',
        'type'  => 'checkbox_group',
        'options' => array (
            'Agraria' => array (
                'label' => __('Agraria','maismeta'),
                'value' => 'Agraria'
            ),
            'Economia' => array (
                'label' => __('Economia','maismeta'),
                'value' => 'Economia'
            ),
            'Farmacia' => array (
                'label' => __('Farmacia','maismeta'),
                'value' => 'Farmacia'
            ),
            'Giurisprudenza' => array (
                'label' => __('Giurisprudenza','maismeta'),
                'value' => 'Giurisprudenza'
            ),
            'Ingegneriea' => array (
                'label' => __('Ingegneriea','maismeta'),
                'value' => 'Ingegneriea'
            ),
            'Lettere e Filosofia' => array (
                'label' => __('Lettere e Filosofia','maismeta'),
                'value' => 'Lettere e Filosofia'
            ),
            'Lingue e letteratura straniera' => array (
                'label' => __('Lingue e letteratura straniera','maismeta'),
                'value' => 'Lingue e letteratura straniera'
            ),
            'Medicina e chirurgia' => array (
                'label' => __('Medicina e chirurgia','maismeta'),
                'value' => 'Medicina e chirurgia'
            ),
            'Scienze della formazione' => array (
                'label' => __('Scienze della formazione','maismeta'),
                'value' => 'Scienze della formazione'
            ),
            'Scienze matematiche fisiche e naturali' => array (
                'label' => __('Scienze matematiche fisiche e naturali','maismeta'),
                'value' => 'Scienze matematiche fisiche e naturali'
            ),
            'Scienze politiche' => array (
                'label' => __('Scienze politiche','maismeta'),
                'value' => 'Scienze politiche'
            )
        )
    ),

);

/* jQuery era qui */

// The Callback
function show_custom_meta_box() {
    global $custom_meta_fields, $post;
    // Use nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

    // Begin the field table and loop
    echo '<table class="form-table">';
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
        // get value of this field if it exists for this post
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
        // begin a table row with
        echo '<tr>
                <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                <td>';
                switch($field['type']) {
                    // text
                    case 'text':
                        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" />
                                <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                    break;
                    // textarea
                    case 'textarea':
                        echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea>
                                <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                    break;
                    // checkbox
                    case 'checkbox':
                        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" ',$meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '','/>
                                <label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['desc'].'</label>';
                    break;
                    // select
                    case 'select':
                        echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'">';
                        foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                            echo '<option', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '', ' value="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</option>';
                        }
                        echo '</select><br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                    break;
                    // radio
                    case 'radio':
                        foreach ( $field['options'] as $option ) {
                            echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$option['value'].'" value="'.$option['value'].'" ',$meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '',' />
                                    <label for="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</label><br />';
                        }
                        echo '<span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                    break;
                    // checkbox_group
                    case 'checkbox_group':
                        foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                            echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$option['value'].'" name="'.$field['id'].'[]" id="'.$option['value'].'"',$meta && in_array($option['value'], $meta) ? ' checked="checked"' : '',' /> 
                                    <label for="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</label><br />';
                        }
                        echo '<span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                    break;
                    // tax_select
                    case 'tax_select':
                        echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'">
                                <option value="">Select One</option>'; // Select One
                        $terms = get_terms($field['id'], 'get=all');
                        $selected = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $field['id']);
                        foreach ($terms as $term) {
                            if (!empty($selected) && !strcmp($term->slug, $selected[0]->slug)) 
                                echo '<option value="'.$term->slug.'" selected="selected">'.$term->name.'</option>'; 
                            else
                                echo '<option value="'.$term->slug.'">'.$term->name.'</option>'; 
                        }
                        $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($field['id']);
                        echo '</select><br /><span class="description"><a href="'.get_bloginfo('home').'/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy='.$field['id'].'">Manage '.$taxonomy->label.'</a></span>';
                    break;
                    // post_list
                    case 'post_list':
                    $items = get_posts( array (
                        'post_type' => $field['post_type'],
                        'posts_per_page' => -1
                    ));
                        echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'">
                                <option value="">Select One</option>'; // Select One
                            foreach($items as $item) {
                                echo '<option value="'.$item->ID.'"',$meta == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>'.$item->post_type.': '.$item->post_title.'</option>';
                            } // end foreach
                        echo '</select><br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                    break;
                    // date
                    case 'date':
                        echo '<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" />
                                <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                    break;
                    // slider
                    case 'slider':
                    $value = $meta != '' ? $meta : '0';
                        echo '<div id="'.$field['id'].'-slider"></div>
                                <input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$value.'" size="5" />
                                <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                    break;
                    // image
                    global $secondazona;$secondazona = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);
                    case 'image':
                        $zonaimmi = $secondazona.'images/image.png';    
                        echo '<span class="custom_default_image" style="display:none">'.$zonaimmi.'</span>';
                        if ($meta) { $zonaimmi = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta, 'medium');  $zonaimmi = $zonaimmi[0]; }             
                        echo    '<input name="'.$field['id'].'" type="hidden" class="custom_upload_image" value="'.$meta.'" />
                                    <img src="'.$zonaimmi.'" class="custom_preview_image" alt="" /><br />
                                        <input class="custom_upload_image_button button" type="button" value="Choose Image" />
                                        <small>&nbsp;<a href="#" class="custom_clear_image_button">Remove Image</a></small>
                                        <br clear="all" /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                    break;
                    // repeatable
                    case 'repeatable':
                        echo '<a class="repeatable-add button" href="#">+</a>
                                <ul id="'.$field['id'].'-repeatable" class="custom_repeatable">';
                        $i = 0;
                        if ($meta) {
                            foreach($meta as $row) {
                                echo '<li><span class="sort hndle">|||</span>
                                            <input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'['.$i.']" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$row.'" size="30" />
                                            <a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a></li>';
                                $i++;
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo '<li><span class="sort hndle">|||</span>
                                        <input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'['.$i.']" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="" size="30" />
                                        <a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a></li>';
                        }
                        echo '</ul>
                            <span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                    break;
                } //end switch
        echo '</td></tr>';
    } // end foreach
    echo '</table>'; // end table
}

function remove_taxonomy_boxes() {
    remove_meta_box('categorydiv', 'post', 'side');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_taxonomy_boxes' );

// Save the Data
function save_custom_meta($post_id) {
    global $custom_meta_fields;

    // verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) 
        return $post_id;
    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;
    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
            return $post_id;
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
    }

    // loop through fields and save the data
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
        if($field['type'] == 'tax_select') continue;
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    } // enf foreach

    // save taxonomies
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $category, 'category' );
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta');


/* nuova posizione */
// enqueue scripts and styles, but only if is_admin

?>
```

As you can see I have 2 sets of checkboxes the first one with 3 possible values:

**'Uomo','Donna','Altro'**
So the user can easily choose 1,2,3 or all the values.

Then I have this to show 2 more coloumns in my edit-post-page:

```
// ALL POST TYPES: posts AND custom post types
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'colonne_informative_head');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'colonna_proprietario', 10, 2);


// ADD NEW COLUMN
function colonne_informative_head($defaults) {
    $defaults['custom_textarea_proprietario'] = 'Proprietario';
    $defaults['custom_checkbox_group_sesso'] = 'Sesso occupanti';
    return $defaults;
};

// SHOW THE FEATURED IMAGE
function colonna_proprietario($column_name, $post_ID) {
    if ($column_name == 'custom_textarea_proprietario') {
        $post_colonna_proprietario = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'custom_textarea_proprietario', true);
        if ($post_colonna_proprietario) {
            echo $post_colonna_proprietario;
        }
    }; 

    if ($column_name == 'custom_checkbox_group_sesso') {
        $sesso_occupanti = get_post_meta($post_ID, "custom_checkbox_group_sesso", true);
      //check that we have a custom field
      if ($sesso_occupanti != "")
      {
        // Separate our comma separated list into an array
        $sesso_occupanti = explode(",", $sesso_occupanti);
        //loop through our new array
        foreach ($sesso_occupanti as $sesso)
        {
          echo $sesso ;
        }
      }
        }; 
    };
```

I have no problem with coloumn named:  **custom_textarea_proprietario** because it was relatively easy to echo only 1 value.

But I have no idea about how to echo the values of second coloumn named: **custom_checkbox_group_sesso** actually it only echoes  '**Array**' and nothing else.
If I open Php my admin and look for the data I'm storing I can see this:

**a:3:{i:0;s:4:"Uomo";i:1;s:5:"Donna";i:2;s:14:"Giurisprudenza";}**

What i would like to echo in my coloumn in that case is:

- Uomo
- Donna

Then one more coloumn with:

- Giurisprudenza

I'm almost a newbie in this kind of things so please be nice with me and try to explain things step by step.

Answer (score 1):

The error was here: (Thank you @Rarst)

```
 if ($column_name == 'custom_checkbox_group_sesso') {
            $sesso_occupanti = get_post_meta($post_ID, "custom_checkbox_group_sesso", true);
          //check that we have a custom field
          if ($sesso_occupanti != "")
          {
            // Separate our comma separated list into an array
            $sesso_occupanti = explode(",", $sesso_occupanti);
            //loop through our new array
            foreach ($sesso_occupanti as $sesso)
            {
              echo $sesso ;
            }
          }
            };
```

All I had to do was to delete this sentence:

```
$sesso_occupanti = explode(",", $sesso_occupanti);
```

Because, as @Rarst [said](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5185572#5185572):

> if you are storing array then you get back array as well and don't
>   need to explode it.